# Python web scraping - access HTML after a few seconds?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm using Python to access this site and scrape the HTML: http://forum.toribash.com/tori_spy.php

As you can see, if you access that webpage, the content changes over the duration of a few seconds. This is a page that shows the most recent posts on a forum and I'm making a Discord bot that would be able to show the most recent post.

Right now, it shows the first post in that list **before** any animations/changes take place.

I was wondering if there's a way for me to skip the animations or make the program wait a few seconds after access before it grabs all the HTML.

Current code:

```
    if message.content.startswith("-post"):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, ":arrows_counterclockwise: **Accessing forums...**")
        await client.send_typing(message.channel)
        time.sleep(5)
        #access site
        session_requests = requests.session()
        url = "http://forum.toribash.com/tori_spy.php"
        result = session_requests.get(url,headers = dict(referer = url))
        #access html
        tree = html.fromstring(result.content)

        list_stuff=[]
        for atag in tree.xpath("//strong/a"): #search for <strong><a>
            list_stuff.append(atag.text_content())
        await client.send_message(message.channel, ":white_check_mark: Last post was in the thread **"+list_stuff[0]+"**")
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: The content you're looking for is loaded via AJAX (open developer tools on Firefox/Chrome and look for `xhr` requests on the network tab). Problem is the URL for the requests is generated dynamically, so I don't see how you can imitate the request unless you understand how the URL is created.

Comment: In HTML you can find <script> with `highestid = 9297850;` - it is last message's number. And then you can use it with url http://forum.toribash.com/vaispy.php?do=xml&last=9297850 to get newer message(s). In message you can find new `id` to get next messages.

Answer (score 0):

Page uses `ajax`/`xhr` to load new posts. It uses url like this

```
forum.toribash.com/vaispy.php?do=xml&last=9297850&r=0....
```

`last` is last message's id which you can find in `HTML`  as 
`highestid = 9297850;` in some `<script>` tag. `r` seems not important - at least code works for me without `r`.

After you get `highestid` you can use it to get `XML` with the newest messages.

In `XML` you can see its ID as `<postid>` so you can use it in next request.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

s = requests.session()

result = s.get("http://forum.toribash.com/tori_spy.php")
tree = html.fromstring(result.content)

for script in tree.xpath("//script"):
    if script.text and 'highestid' in script.text:
        highestid = script.text.split('\n')[3]
        highestid = highestid[13:-1]
        print('highestid:', highestid)

        result = s.get('http://forum.toribash.com/vaispy.php?do=xml&last='+highestid, headers=dict(referer=url))
        #print(result.text)
        data = html.fromstring(result.content)

        for item in data.xpath('.//event'):
            print('--- event ---')
            print('id:', item.xpath('.//id')[0].text)
            print('postid:', item.xpath('.//postid')[0].text)
            print(item.xpath('.//preview')[0].text)
```

Current result (yours can be different)

```
highestid: 9297873
--- event ---
id: 9297883
postid: 9297883
me vende esse full valkyrie por 18k
--- event ---
id: 9297881
postid: 9297881
Congratz Goat! Welcome to the team! :)
--- event ---
id: 9297879
postid: 9297879
Try to reset your email password, then attempt to do what I suggested.
--- event ---
id: 9297877
postid: 9297877
Hello Nope. Most of these bugs are known to currently cause issues and they are being worked on. People pinging and rejoining are bots that are being dealt with (it's just an extensive process to...
--- event ---
id: 9297874
postid: 9297874
Bon courage :)
```